# how can i get min and max value from my collection in this kind of query mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get min and max value of a property named productPrice from my collection of docs
how can I do soo..?

Also, I cannot use multiple finds as  it shows cursor error

```
        let query = collection
            .find(JSON.parse(queryStr))
            .sort(
                req.query.sort === "discount"
                    ? { discountPercent: -1 }
                    : req.query.sort === "high"
                    ? { productPrice: -1 }
                    : req.query.sort === "low"
                    ? { productPrice: 1 }
                    : req.query.sort === "rating"
                    ? { productRating: -1 }
                    : null,
            )
            .collation({ locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true })
            .limit(limit)
            .skip(startIndex)
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your schema, data example or expected output and answering your questiong "how to get max and min value":

The first thing come to my mind is... do two queries:

```js
var min = await db.collection.find(yourFilter).sort({ "productPrice": -1 }).limit(1)
var max = await db.collection.find(yourFilter).sort({ "productPrice": 1 }).limit(1)
```

But, without knowing your schema, maybe this can help you:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "max": {
        "$max": "$productPrice"
      },
      "min": {
        "$min": "$productPrice"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is only the `$group` stage, if you add a filter with `$match` and group by an specific field you can get the data you want.

The result is like this:

```json
{
   "_id": null,
   "max": 8,
   "min": 1
}
```

Where you get the max and min value.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B643tO4Qjrl)